# Predicate all non null fields

Tags: java, java-stream, predicate

I'm having simple `Book` class that contains fields like

```
private String ISBN;
private String title;
private String author;
```

I want to create search query, that will take `BookDto` as criteria, and compare all non nullable fields with elements of my `List<Book>`. So I wrote few simple `Predicates`

```
private Predicate<Book> matchingAuthor(Book another) {
    return book -> book.getAuthor() != null && book.getAuthor().equals(another.getAuthor());
}

private Predicate<Book> matchingTitle(Book another) {
    return book -> book.getTitle() != null && book.getTitle().equals(another.getTitle());
}

private Predicate<Book> matchingISBN(Book another) {
    return book -> book.getISBN() != null && book.getISBN().equals(another.getISBN());
}
```

And I'd like to have 1 search method that will handle all the logic

```
private List<BookDto> findMatchingBooks(BookDto criteria) {
        return books.stream().map(BookConverter::toEntity).filter(this::matchingBook).map(BookConverter::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

But this logic is ugly... and it wont work as I want.

```
private Predicate<Book> matchingBook(Book criteria) {
    if(criteria.getISBN() != null) {
        return matchingISBN(criteria);
    } 
    else if(criteria.getISBN() == null && criteria.getTitle() == null && criteria.getAuthor() != null) {
        return matchingAuthor(criteria);
    }
     else if(criteria.getISBN() == null && criteria.getTitle() != null && criteria.getAuthor() != null) {
        return matchingAuthor(criteria) && matchingTitle(criteria);
    }
}
```

First two `if/else` are lets say ok (ugly but working), third one is causing

> bad operand types for binary operator '&&'
>         first type:  Predicate
>         second type: Predicate

And the question is, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How about adding some boolean methods in to the `Book` class itself, e.g. `boolean hasSameAuthor(Book other)`?

Comment: Aside: Its not really clear what `return books.stream().map(BookConverter::toEntity).filter(this::matchingBook).map(BookConverter::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());` is performing. How does `filter(this::matchingBook)` work with the current signature? Also note a missing return in your `matchingBook` method. Could defualt to true as `return book -> true;`

Comment: Just a hunch, you're possibly looking for a simple chained or conditions to match attributes one by one or else returns false. Something like :`matchingISBN(criteria).or(matchingAuthor(criteria)).or(matchingTitle(criteria));`

Comment: Your conditions are redundant. When you did `if(criteria.getISBN() != null) { …}`, you don’t need `else if(criteria.getISBN() == null …`, as it must be `null` at this point. The same applies to the other conditions. This method won’t even compile as the compiler does not recognize the redundancy and will say that there must be another `return` at the end. Just use `return criteria.getISBN() != null? matchingISBN(criteria): criteria.getTitle() == null? matchingAuthor(criteria): matchingAuthor(criteria).and(matchingTitle(criteria));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your predicates using [`and`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and(java.util.function.Predicate)):

```
return matchingAuthor(criteria).and(matchingTitle(criteria));
```

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and another.

Comment: Regarding the logic it should be Or. 1) match isbn or 2) match author...

Comment: @swinkler: Where do you get that from?

Comment: Maybe I misread MatchingBook method, it states: if isbn present, return isbn predicate. OR: if author (and only author) is present, return author predicate... Why and?

Comment: Because of `return matchingAuthor(criteria) && matchingTitle(criteria)`. Both must match if both are present.

Comment: Sure. This is the last condition. I wrote about the two before.

Comment: Those will stay untouched. There are no combined predicates.

Comment: Regarding the particular question you are absolutely right. I was focusing on the whole predicate chain (isbn or author or (author and title)) - sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [`Predicate::and`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and-java.util.function.Predicate-) to combine the `Predicates`:

```
return matchingAuthor(criteria).and(matchingTitle(criteria));
```

---

`default Predicate<T> and(Predicate<? super T> other)`:

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and another. When evaluating the composed predicate, if this predicate is false, then the other predicate is not evaluated.
>   Any exceptions thrown during evaluation of either predicate are relayed to the caller; if evaluation of this predicate throws an exception, the other predicate will not be evaluated.